# Change div-element according to input element range

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, range

I created this simple input range (with value from 0 to 100) and a div-element(#boxColor).
What I would like to achieve, is that when I drag the input range slider to the left (below value 33), box changes color to green. Also, if I drag the input range slider to the right (above 66), The color of the box should change to red. Between values 34-65 box should remain blue. 
Would anyone here know how to achieve this?

```js
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
if (x = "50") {
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "new";
}
}
```

```css
#boxColor {
width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue; margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
<p>Custom range slider:</p>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>  
    
<div id="boxColor"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to console.log out your values?

Comment: Hey, I haven't, and not entirely sure what do you mean? Could you explain more please?

Comment: check my answer below:  if (x = "50"){ } would return a string if you logged it to the console like console.log (x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few issues there I cannot explain them all but there is a value missing, also logging innerHTML will not change the background of your element you have to use style properties for that.

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
<p>Custom range slider:</p>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="myRange" step="2">
</div>  
<div id="box"></div>

const slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
slider.addEventListener('input', myFunction);
var box = document.querySelector('#box');

function myFunction() {
let x = this.value;

console.log(x);

box.innerHTML = x;
if(x < 33){
box.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
else if(x > 65){
box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
else{
box.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
 }
}


#box {
width: 100px; 
height: 100px;
background: blue;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dsgqtwko/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can change the style of the box-element by listening to the input-event on the slider-element, like so:

```js
const slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
const box = document.getElementById('boxColor');

slider.oninput = ({ target: { value } }) => {
  if (+value < 33) box.style.background = 'green';
  else if (+value > 66) box.style.background = 'red';
  else box.style.background = 'blue';
}
```

```css
#boxColor {
width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue; margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
<p>Custom range slider:</p>
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>  
    
<div id="boxColor"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event handler to call a function that performs the color change based on the current value of the slider. See below for an example:

```js
function handleChange() {

  var x = document.getElementById('myRange').value;
  let color;
  if (x <= 33) {
    color = 'green';
  } else if (x >= 66) {
    color = 'red';
  } else {
    color = 'blue';
  }
  document.getElementById('boxColor').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
#boxColor {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <label for="myRange">Custom range slider:</label>
  <input 
    type="range" 
    min="1" 
    max="100" 
    value="50" 
    class="slider" 
    id="myRange" 
    onchange="handleChange()" 
  />
</div>

<div id="boxColor"></div>
```

Comment: I got two correct answers but prefer this one because on this one the value changes already when dragging the pointer, not when you finish dragging it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are perfectly fine. But I improved them slightly , so that, you can style the box more freely based on the value change.

```js
function handleChange(event) {
  const { value } = event.target;
  const box = document.querySelector('.boxColor');
  
  if(value <= 33) {
    box.classList.add('boxColor--green');
  }else {
    box.classList.remove('boxColor--green');
  }
  
  if(value > 33 && value <= 65) {
    box.classList.add('boxColor--blue');
  }else {
    box.classList.remove('boxColor--blue');
  }
  
  if(value > 65) {
    box.classList.add('boxColor--red');
  }else {
   box.classList.remove('boxColor--red')
  }
  
}
```

```css
.boxColor {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue; margin-top: 20px;
}

.boxColor--green {
  background-color: green;
}

.boxColor--red {
  background-color: red;
}

.boxColor--blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
 <p>Custom range slider:</p>
 <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange"
       oninput="handleChange(event)">
</div>  

<div class="boxColor"></div>
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for this! Very helpful. Might be a stupid question, but would you happen to know how to change the values of the box already when you are dragging the range handeler, not only when you let it go. Hope you understood what I meant :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please, check it out again. I replaced onchange method with oninput method.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to hear that.

Comment: Little off topic, but I was wondering also if you would know how to add link to different colors? So, everytime the color of the box changes, the link changes as well?

Comment: You can use this - document.querySelector('.boxColor').href = ''newlink';. Add this line inside every if statement.

Comment: Note that above change will only work if the element is anchor tag (<a/>)